# Dynamically access dynamic class instance property

Tags: typescript

I need to dynamically create a property on the class instance that is declared as `static` property on the class itself.
In the following example, I need to have a class instance property `isbn`

```js
class Model {
  static identifier = 'isbn'

  getIdentifier() {
     if(this[Model.identifier]){ // <- error
       return this[Model.identifier] // <- error
     }
     else {
       return Math.random()
     }
  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Model'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Model'.